# inherited variable of class2 is different from class1 (C#)

Tags: c#, inheritance

I just made a class Shapes and an other 2 classes ('Triangle' & 'Square') which inherit from 'Shapes'.

```
public class Shapes
{
    private int sides;
}

public class Triangle : Shapes
{
    public void init()
    {
        int sides = 3;
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Square : Shapes
{
    public void init()
    {
        int sides = 4;
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*Code is designed using Classdiagram*

Question: How should I call the class so that it shows how many sides does a shape has?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever used Constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a protected member sides which is used within the init-section of every shape:

```
public class Shapes
{
    protected readonly int sides;
    public int NumberOfSides { get { return sides; } } 
}

public class Triangle : Shapes
{
    public Triangle()
    {
        this.sides = 3;
    }
}

public class Square : Shapes
{
    public Square()
    {
        this.sides = 4;
    }
}
```

As Farhad Jabiyev mentioned using constructors is the usual way to initialize a new instance (see my code above)

Now when you call `Shape#NumberOfSides` you get 3 for `Triangle` and 4 for `Square`:

```
Shape square = new Square();
int number = square.NumberOfSides();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a property on the class that has an accessor like this

```
public class Shapes
{
    private int sides;

    public int NumberOfSides { get { return sides; } } 
}
```

Then you can go `mySquare.NumberOfSides`

Comment: so example if I want to get the number of sides of a square I need to initialise it as `Square mySquare = new Square()
Console.WriteLine(mySquare.NumberOfSides)`

Comment: Defining sides private won´t solve his issue for triangles, hence they have three sides. You may use protected member instead